# How to Create the Edit/Delete/Create Views With a Code first database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, code-first

This Is my model for my ClientController

```
namespace CV_Website.Models
{
public class Clients
{
    [Key]

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
```

.......

```
    public List<CV> cVs;

}
public class CV
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Job { get; set; }
    public bool Public { get; set; }
}
}
```

And my DbContext

```
namespace CV_Website.Models
{
public class ClientsContext : DbContext
{
 public ClientsContext() : base("name=ClientsContext")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Clients> Clients { get; set; }

}
```

I've been able to Populate the View With hard coded users (made for testing) but not from the model

this is my hard coded users

```
 public List<Clients> GenerateCV()
    {
     data.AllClients.Clear()
     List<Clients> result = new List<Clients>();
     List<ClientsContext> contexts = new List<ClientsContext>()
     Clients test = new Clients
     {
         Name = "John",
         Age = 18,
         Gender = "Male",
```

...
         };

```
     Clients test2 = new Clients
     {
         Name = "Sam",
         Age = 18, 
         Public = true
```

...
};

```
        result.Add(test);
        result.Add(test2);

        return result;
    }`
```

I'm not certain how to add the Create/Edit/View ,views using the MVC Scaffolding tool and i would mostly get a System.NullReferenceException 
I'm still new at coding and not sure what I'm doing wrong 
Thanks in Advance

Comment: i think following a basic on-line tutorial would be more time effective for increasing your knowledge around this technology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, classes should be nouns according to [Microsoft's naming conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/names-of-classes-structs-and-interfaces), so I would rename Clients to Client.


As you said you don't have issues with the database, I will focus on controllers and views.

## List Clients

The following action in your client controller would return a list of clients from your database to a View:

```
// GET: CV_Website/Clients/ClientList
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult ClientList()
{
    //using statement disposes the connection to the database once query has completed
    using (var context = new ClientContext())
    {
        //.ToList runs the query and maps the result to List<Client>
        var clients = context.Clients.ToList();
    }

    //Return view with list of clients as the model
    return View("ClientList", clients);
}
```

Simply right-click anywhere within this method and select Add View to create the view.

If you select 'List' as the template and 'Client (CV_Website.Models)' as the Model class, it will create a View that lists the details for each client in the list.


In the View, you can see the following lines of code:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
```

These are the URL's that point to actions within your controller.

## Edit Client

As an example, here is the implementation for Edit:

```
//Added third parameter to clearly point to 'Client' controller
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Client", new { id=item.ID })
```

This URL points to an action named Edit in the client controller that will read another View named 'Edit'. The implementation would look similar to this:

```
// GET: CV_Website/Clients/Edit/1
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    using (var context = new ClientContext())
    {
        //Using Linq, select the client with the matching ID or return null
        var client = context.Clients.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);
    }

    return View("ClientList", client);
}
```

Once again, right-click and select Add View. This time choose the Edit template and the client model again.

This will create a View with a form that can be submitted to the controller. To improve readability, I would write the using statement like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Client", FormMethod.Post))
```

The implementation of the Edit action would be similar to this:

```
// POST: CV_Website/Clients/Edit/{Client}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Client client)
{
    using (var context = new ClientContext())
    {
        //Get client from database
        var clientInDb = context.Clients.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Id == client.ID);

        //Update client using properties from the client parameter
        clientInDb.Age = client.Age;
        clientInDb.Gender = client.Gender;
        clientInDb.Name = client.Name;
        clientInDb.Surname = client.Surname;

        //Commit changes to the database
        context.SaveChanges();
    }

    return View("ClientList", client);
}
```

This updates the client in the database and saves the changes.



I hope this helps to get you started.

More information on DbContext [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/working-with-dbcontext)

Answer (score 0):

Code first creates a database for us based on our classes, Please refer the following links for your answer:

[Basics for code first approach](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/what-is-code-first.aspx)

[Code first demo](https://github.com/entityframeworktutorial/EF6-Code-First-Demo)

Comment: Creating the Database is not the problem.To add the control the data with an MVC application is where I'm struggling